# C++ overloading and inheritance, call new method

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a class A:

```
class A {
  public:
  do_end(){
    finish...
  }
  do_something(){
    stuff is done...
    do_end();
  }
}
```

and class B, which derives from A:

```
class B :public A {
  public:
  do_end(){
    finish differently...
  }
}
```

now when I do:

```
B b;
b.do_something();
```

the do_end() method of A is called. 
How do I use the do_something() of A but have it call the method do_end() of B?

Is there a way?

Thanks

Comment: Please post real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define function do_end in class A as having the function specifier virtual

```
  virtual SomeType do_end(){
    finish...
  }
```